# Using Google Sheets as a Web Scraper for a Site with Java

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to use `IMPORTXML()` to scrape information from the following website.

https://libbyapp.com/library/lapl/search/audiobooks/query-john%20scalzi/language-en/page-1

After no success with the command and some digging online, it seems that this command will not work because the website uses java to render the information.

Is there any other command or method within google sheets to scrape some information from this web page?  Specifically I'm trying to get the names and authors of the first 3 books listed.

Answer (score 0):

No, not Java. JavaScript. Very different things.

Lucky for you, the site has a JSON API! You can see this for yourself in your browser's network monitor. That means there's no pure-formula for this, but we can write a simple userscript (Tools > Script Editor).

We make this user-defined function (paste into the editor):

```js
function getAuthors(url, showHeaders) 
{
  let jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  let object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
  
  let bookData = showHeaders ? 
    [ ['Title', 'Author(s)'] ] : 
    [];

  bookData = bookData.concat(
      object.items.map(item => (
      // Title is always first, followed by any authors:
      [item.title].concat(
        item.creators
          // Add more creator roles here:
          .filter(creator => creator.role === 'Author')
          // Take creator's name
          .map(author => author.name)
          // Comma-separated
          .join(',')
      ))
    )
  );
  
  return bookData;
}
```

Using the Network Monitor, I determined that the URL of interest is

```
https://thunder.api.overdrive.com/v2/libraries/lapl/media?overdriveFormats=true&mediaType=audiobook&query=john%20scalzi&language=en&page=1&perPage=24&x-client-id=dewey
```

Then in your sheet, you can use this formula:

```
=getAuthors(A1)
```

or

```
=getAuthors(A1, 1)
```

if you want headers.

If you want the first three, then simply use `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` to truncate the table.

Comment: Thanks Calculuswhiz, this is is working for me! One question: I'm a bit new to this, so could you explain in a little more detail how you acquired the exact URL from the Network Monitor?

Comment: @TomDekkard Yup. If you press F12 on your browser, it should open up your Developer Tools. Likely one of your tabs says "Network". If you navigate to the page or refresh the page with the monitor open, it should capture all the data requests. In this case, I filtered by XHR's (usually the first thing I check after the site), and found the URL that returned the response with the right data.